# Is there a way to boost based on value of an index property in Hybris solr?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solr-query-syntax, solr-boost, solr7

We have a requirement wherein we need to make boosting for a field dynamic. Let's say that we have an indexed property foo, we need to perform a mathematical calculation on foo to determine its boost value which would be different for every product.

Is this doable in Hybris Solr?

Note: I'm using SAP CX 2105 and Solr 8.9.0 with Dismax Query Parse.
And above requirement can be done in standalone Solr application as following.

```
@Resource
private SolrQuery solrQuery;

private void addBoosts()
{
    solrQuery.add("boost", "sub(20, sqrt(field(foo)))");
}
```

In Hybris, I have tried following

```
@Resource
private SearchQuery searchQuery;

private void addBoosts()
{
    searchQuery.addQuery("boost", "sub(20, sqrt(field(foo)))");
}
```

And also this

```
@Resource
private SearchQuery searchQuery;

private void addBoosts()
{
    searchQuery.addQuery("boost", "sub(20, sqrt(field(foo)))");
}
```

Both don't affect search order of the result.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? I think it amounts to using the eDisMax query parser’s [boost](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/edismax-query-parser.html#extended-dismax-parameters) parameter, eg. `{!boost b=log(foo)}term` creates a query "term" which is boosted by the function query `log(foo)` (each document matching "term" receives it's own multiplicative boost according to the value of log(foo)). Here you would just put the terms of the main query instead of "term".

Comment: Hi @EricLavault, Thanks for reply, I have added more details and context in question.

Comment: I don't know if your code is doing properly what I suggest. The first step would be to tweak the query via [Solr Admin UI](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/query-screen.html), by checking how boosting affects scoring (add 'score' to fl parameter and use debugQuery if necessary). Also, you mention the dismax query parser, but the `{!boost}` syntax works with **e**dismax only (see the checkboxes in Admin UI). Then once you got something suitable, you would implement it in your solr client.